# Mysql function trim doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I tried trim function many times to remove white spaces on a table column but it didn't .

```
update table_name set column_name=  TRIM(column_name)
```

any guide please.
[image]

Comment: `TRIM()` removes leading and trailing whitespace. Are you trying to remove all whitespace?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't". According to the documentation trim will remove leading/trailing/both spaces. Are you trying to remove spaces in the inner of the column(e.x "John Doe")

Comment: @vhu yes or at least white spaces at the left side

Comment: Consider changing your tags. This is not a `java` or `jdbc` question at all.

Comment: @Tavo I need a java solution if there is no MySQL solution

Comment: What is your exact requirement? To remove white spaces on left? To remove white spaces on right? To remove white spaces from both left and right? To remove white spaces from in between? To remove all of them?

Comment: remove white spaces from both left and right?

Comment: @JavaFan Could you show some sample data of column_name?

Comment: @kuttyraj  I have edited my post.

Comment: @JavaFan Did you try this now my new solution? It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do `SELECT REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '') FROM table_name`?

Comment: it gives the desired result but when I add where condition it didn't give it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when I add while condition". Can you edit your question with an update? Or ask a new question, as this seems to have been resolved.

Comment: Of course it won't give you. The replace removes spaces from the returned data, while in the where clause you are comparing with the current data in the database( which has the spaces). You should put the replace/trim operator also in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the white spaces from both left and right side, `trim()` should do the work for you.

You can check the length of the returned values as follows:

```
select trim(column_name), char_length(trim(column_name)) as length from table_name
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884e9/4) demo

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.

Try this,

```
update yourtablename set price = REPLACE( price, ' ', '');
```

[image]

Comment: I think the question is about the data in the column and not the column name.

Comment: @kuttyraj  It doesn't work , I have tried it previously

Comment: @JavaFan Did you try this now my new solution? It is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it , it gives duplicate entry error 
Error Code: 1062

Comment: @JavaFan what are all the fieldnames in that table other than price? did you use the where condition while update?

Comment: @kuttyraj  price,site_comment,img_link,buy_link,service_id [FK] are my field names, I get this error without using where condition !

Comment: Just add where 1=1. Did you try this, update yourtablename set price = REPLACE( price, ' ', '') where 1=1;